# Laravel Authorization can always return false for API

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authorization

I am trying to use Laravel authorization policies with API and Sanctum. However, I use middleware on the route as follows.

```php
Route::get('/user/orders/{order}', 
    [OrderController::class, 'get_user_order_detail'])
    ->middleware('can:view:order');
```

**OrderPolicy.php**

```php
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class OrderPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // dd(1);
    }

    public function view(User $user, Order $order): bool
    {
        return $user->id === $order->user_id;
    }
}
```

As you see, when I add `dd(1)` inside the constructor of the OrderPolicy, then I get `1` as expected, but when I move it to the inside of `view` function, I get `unauthorized` which indicates that is maybe the `view` function itself is not being called, but, the OrderPolicy is getting called.

Comment: did you register your policy ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#registering-policies

Comment: is not it should be auto-discovered? as per documentation if I name my police as ModelPolicy and it is at or above level of models then it should be auto-discovered, and as you see the constructor of the class is being called, but not the needed function

Comment: is is working .? not working so just use this

Comment: It doesn't auto register. Because the laravel Auth Service Provider has no idea what rules to add to what. @KamleshPaul has provided you with the correct answer.

Comment: Use `can:view,order` instead of a second `:`

Comment: @KamleshPaul registered, still not working

Comment: @apokryfos did what you said, still not working

Answer (score 1):

Your middleware definition is wrong:

```
->middleware('can:view:order')
```

it should be:

```
->middleware('can:view,order')
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-middleware):

Laravel includes a middleware that can authorize actions before the incoming request even reaches your routes or controllers. By default, the `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize` middleware is assigned the `can` key in your `App\Http\Kernel` class. Let's explore an example of using the `can` middleware to authorize that a user can update a post:

```
use App\Models\Post;

Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,post');
```

> In this example, we're passing the `can` middleware two arguments. The
> first is the name of the action we wish to authorize and the second is
> the route parameter we wish to pass to the policy method. In this
> case, since we are using [implicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding), a `App\Models\Post`
> model will be passed to the policy method. If the user is not
> authorized to perform the given action, an HTTP response with a 403
> status code will be returned by the middleware.